# React Native: the App isn`t being updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to save my app and it isn`t being saved.

I did one change within the text tag and saved and the android app showed the change immediatly. But afterwards i did more changes and even though i saved, every time i open the app it comes back to the previous time it has been saved.

I tried closing and opening again the command line interface and run again the app. But it always comes back to the previous situation instead of the new version.

```
 export default class app extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text>נבנה המקדש!</Text>
             <Text>במהרה בימינו!</Text>
             <Text>נבנה המקדש!</Text><Text>ה' הוא המלך!</Text>
           </View>
         );
       }
     }
```

This is the code expected. The only changes were in the text tags in both times.

But they don`t appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a value for when user close/open app, You have to save your data in the user's device. To do this, you can use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage).